# Rails 4 - nested resource under singleton resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, nested-routes

I have a Rails 4 app and currently implementing a shopping cart.
i dont want to reveal the user id, cart id but only the cart items id in the url.
so basically, i want my routes to be something like ;-

```
/user/cart/plans => show all plans
/user/cart/cart_items/new => add to cart
/user/cart => show current cart with cart items
/user/cart/cart_item DESTROY - delete item from cart
```

so in my `routes.rb`

```
resource :user, only: [:edit] do
  collection do
    patch 'update_password'
    get 'show_payment_history'
  end
  resource :cart
  resources :cart_items ,  only: [:new, :destroy]   
  ...
  ...
```

and the path, that go generated using above routes is ...

```
   update_password_user PATCH    /user/update_password(.:format)                                                                             users#update_password
                             show_payment_history_user GET      /user/show_payment_history(.:format)                                                                        users#show_payment_history
                                             user_cart POST     /user/cart(.:format)                                                                                        carts#create
                                         new_user_cart GET      /user/cart/new(.:format)                                                                                    carts#new
                                        edit_user_cart GET      /user/cart/edit(.:format)                                                                                   carts#edit
                                                       GET      /user/cart(.:format)                                                                                        carts#show
                                                       PATCH    /user/cart(.:format)                                                                                        carts#update
                                                       PUT      /user/cart(.:format)                                                                                        carts#update
                                                       DELETE   /user/cart(.:format)                                                                                        carts#destroy
                                    new_user_cart_item GET      /user/cart_items/new(.:format)                                                                              cart_items#new
                                        user_cart_item DELETE   /user/cart_items/:id(.:format)                                                                              cart_items#destroy
```

But i am still not able to make it work,For example, `user_cart_path` do not work in redirection, dont know...whats the issue.

Any help will be appreciated or any good approach for my suggested solution!

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "do not work" what exactly happens?

Comment: Started GET "/user/cart" for 103.211.42.252 at 2018-02-22 10:58:52 +0000
Cannot render console from 103.211.42.252! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant CartsController):

Comment: let me try to pluralize it and run agan

Comment: Yeah...its resolved by pluralising it.Closing this question now

Comment: Why its downvoted...kindly clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to pluralizing the controller name.Once i renamed the controller from `cart` to `carts`...everything got fixed.

Hope it helps others